# Not storing Item in variable

Tags: solidity, testing, error

I am working on making a game where users can collect items. I have chosen to store the ERC721 tokens that represent the items in this way:

Item struct: [image: Image of item struct]

User struct and map that maps account-addresses to user-structs:
[image: User Struct and map]

I made some functions to test this out:

[image: functions]

As seen, getItem does in fact not get an item, but rather how many items a user has. This is done for testing, and will be changed back when it works.

I then created some tests to try this out:
[image: Test]

This outputs as follows:

[image]

As you see, the createItem adds an item to the array, but when GetItem is called, it is no longer there. When I called createItem from within getItem, it worked as expected. But for some reason this is not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please share your actual code and output, not screenshots. Screenshots are not searchable (so not useful to future developers looking for help) and are inaccessible to people with visual impairments.

Comment: You're using `call` to invoke `createItem`. A call does not send a transaction and thus cannot change blockchain state. You need to send a transaction (probably via `send` instead, depending on what library you're using).

Comment: @smarx Oh okay yeah that makes sense. I'll give that a try. And I will upload actual code next time! My bad